# How do send my JWT token when I make a GET/POST request to the api endpoint through UI?

Tags: html, node.js, express, jwt

So I created Nodejs api and I was accessing it using postman up until now. But now I wanted to create the forntend.
In the api when the user logs in he will get a JWT token and when accessing protected routes he needs to send the JWT token. I was sending the token in header using postman. 
How can I do that through frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside login function, on success, use callback function with jwt parameter to call `localStorage.setItem('userToken', jwt)`. This will put your jwt inside user's browsers local storage. Then, if you are using for example axios for backend calls you should add interceptor that will on every request send jwt as well. Something like this

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(async () => {
  request.headers.common.Authorization = `bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('userToken')}`;
  return request;
}, err => Promise.reject(err));
```

So, it is not going to be exactly like this, but something similar that suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

On Login success store the token in local storage `localStorage.getItem('token')`

Then pass the token to the api in header by fetching it from localStorage